# how to dismiss dropdown when click outside?

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

i am learning react+typescript. i want to implement a control like [fluentui dropdown](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dropdown):

[image]

basically I draw a div and set its position 'relative' then use absolute layout on the dropdown panel. but there is a problem:

how to dismiss the dropdown when click outside area?

Can you share good practices?

Comment: Can you share the code of your component? Also, look into `focus` and `blur` events.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume `dropdown` is dom node of your dropdown area
and `dismissDropdown` function to dismiss it.
Then your code could look like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // if outside of dropdown
    if (!dropdown.contains(e.target)) {
        dismissDropdown()
    }
});
```

contains: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Basically we check if element on which user clicked is inside dropdown or dropdown itself, and if not then dismiss it.